# Render string literal using StaticResource

Tags: xaml, maui

I'm learning MAUI at [Microsoft Learn.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/use-shared-resources/2-define-and-use-resources)

It's reminding me of Silverlight/WPF in the XAML.

Given the following:

```xml
<Label>
    <Label.Resources>
        <OnPlatform x:Key="PlatformName" x:TypeArguments="system:String">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="[iOS]" />
            <On Platform="Android" Value="[ANdroid]" />
            <On Platform="WinUI" Value="[Windows]" />
            <On Platform="MacCatalyst" Value="[macOS]" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Label.Resources>
    <Label.Text>{StaticResource PlatformName}</Label.Text>
</Label>
```

How can I set the `Label.Text` property to the contents of the `PlatformName` resource (being a string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put the StaticResource in the ContentPage.Resource. Such as:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <OnPlatform x:Key="PlatformName" x:TypeArguments="system:String">
         <On Platform="iOS" Value="[iOS]" />
         <On Platform="Android" Value="[ANdroid]" />
         <On Platform="WinUI" Value="[Windows]" />
         <On Platform="MacCatalyst" Value="[macOS]" />
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Label Text="{StaticResource PlatformName}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's no specific reason to use a `StaticResource` then you could just simply do it like this:

```xml
<Label>
    <Label.Text>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="system:String">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="[iOS]" />
            <On Platform="Android" Value="[ANdroid]" />
            <On Platform="WinUI" Value="[Windows]" />
            <On Platform="MacCatalyst" Value="[macOS]" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Label.Text>
</Label>
```

Or in short using the `{OnPlatform}` markup extension:

```xml
<Label
    Text="{OnPlatform iOS='[iOS]', Android='[ANdroid]', WinUI='[Windows]', MacCatalyst='[macOS]'}" />
```